# Anyone know how I can retrieve the data from my email-field that I created with php (i work with a data file)

Tags: php, html

I have a first page where you enter emails in a textbox and there it saves it to a file(data.txt). From here on I made an admin module so I could delete or edit these emails.

My problem is I can't use `$_POST['edited']` to retrieve the edited mail from an input field I create using php (echo) inside my function `Edit`.

If I run this, I get

> array key 'edited' is undefined.

```
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Email</td> <td colspan="2">action</td></tr> 
            <?php

                function Delete($array,$size,$pos)
                {

                    for($i=0;$i<$size-1;$i++)
                    {  
                        
                        if($array[$pos] != $array[$i])
                        {
                            $tmp[$i]=$array[$i];
                        
                        }
                        else{
                            $tmp[$i] = $array[$i+1];
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }

                    $file = fopen("./Date.txt","w");
                    foreach($tmp as $value)
                    {
                        fwrite($file,$value);
                        
                    }
                    fclose($file);
                    header("refresh:0");
                }

                function Edit($array,$size,$pos)
                {
                    
                    echo("<tr><td><input type='email' name='edited'style='width: 90%;'></td>
                    <td colspan='2'><input type='button' name='change' value='submit change'></td></tr>
                  ");
                  if(isset($_POST['change']))
                  {
                    if(!empty(isset($_POST['edited'])))
                    {
                        for($i=0;$i<$size-1;$i++)
                        {  
                        
                            if($array[$pos] != $array[$i])
                            {
                                $tmp[$i]=$array[$i];
                            
                            }
                            else{
                                echo('<tr><td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="Edited" style="width: 95%;"></td><td><input type="submit" value="submit change"></td></tr>');
                                $newedit = $_POST['Edited'];
                                $tmp[$i]=$newedit;
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }

                        $file = fopen("./Date.txt","w");
                        foreach($tmp as $value)
                        {
                            fwrite($file,$value);
                            
                        }
                        fclose($file);

                    }
                  }
                }

                $file = fopen("./Date.txt","r");
                $i=0;
                while(!feof($file))
                {
                    $fullfile[$i] = fgets($file);
                    $i++;
                }
                fclose($file);

                $size = count($fullfile);

                for($j=0; $j<$size-1;$j++)
                {
                    echo("<tr>");
                    echo("<td>".$fullfile[$j]."</td>");
                    echo("<td><button name='Delete' value='$j'>Delete</button></td>");
                    echo('<td><button name="Edit" value="$j">Edit</button></td>');
                    echo("</tr>");
                }

                if(isset($_POST['Delete']))
                {
                    $value = $_POST['Delete'];
                    Delete($fullfile,$size,$value);
                }
                if(isset($_POST['Edit']))
                {

                    $value = $_POST['Edit'];
                    Edit($fullfile,$size,$value);                       
                }
            ?>


        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: "Can't" means what exactly? What happens when you try to run the code? Is all this code really a [mre] of your issue? Try to focus it a bit more, and give a clearer explanation of the problem.

Comment: with can't i mean that it gives me an error when i try using this

Comment: And what is the error, exactly? How can we help if you don't give us the important details?

Comment: If I run this, I get array key 'edited' is undefined. it says it in the question XD

Comment: I see. The question text was quite hard to read due to the complete lack of punctuation or formatting. I've improved it for you - now it's much easier to see the error message and understand the rest of the text.

Comment: Anyway you haven't shown any code where you use `$_POST['edited']` apart from in the `isset()`, which wouldn't cause the error you've mentioned. Which line of code does the error message point to? Is it actually `$newedit = $_SERVER['Edited'];` perhaps? Did you mean to write `$_POST` there, instead of `$_SERVER`?

Comment: Yes you were right it was supposed to be $_POST, but I was trying some other methods to maybe see if it would work but either way it still does not work and gives the same error

Comment: Not sure if it's part of your problem but `if(!empty(isset($_POST['edited'])))` makes no sense. There's no point in testing whether `isset` returns empty or not. Just use `if(isset($_POST['edited']))`, the same way you've tested whether other variables exist or not.